# Step-Up Converter Design

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, boost, low-power

I am trying to design a step-up converter with the following specifications:

- Vin: 3.0 - 3.7 V
- Vout: 30 V
- Iout(max): 50 mA

With such a high boost ratio, my calculated duty cycle would be ~92% which is near the maximum for most controller ICs. Is there a topology that uses a transformer to achieve such a high boost ratio?

Comment: Any transformer based. I would recommend a flyback or possibly push-pull.

Comment: would there be any difficulty with using such a low Vin?

Comment: Bit lower than normal, but you should be able to find plenty. Have you tried TI webench?

Comment: How did you calculate the 92% duty cycle?

Comment: And what's the load regulation requirement?

Comment: @winny , TI webench recommends standard boost converters to me. I am not sure how to get it to show me flyback topologies

Comment: @SteveSh , 1 - (Vin/Vout) with efficiency taken into account

Comment: Given to low current requirement would daisy chaining boost converters be more practical?

Comment: That is something I considered as well - isn't that called an autotransformer

Comment: Something as this could help MAX15032 500kHz, 36V Output, 600mW PWM Step-Up DC-DC Converter

Comment: @RGBEngineer Webench has a check box if you need output isolation, try checking that.  Also, you could use a tapped inductor if you don't need isolation (which isn't really different from a flyback transformer with one side of the windings tied together.)

Comment: @RGBEngineer if you are done here you should really accept one of the answers. If you still have remaining queries leave them below the relevant answer.

Comment: Oh sorry Andy, I thought you were still trying to come up with something.

Comment: @RGBEngineer No, I'm done here unless you have specific queries on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *With such a high boost ratio, my calculated duty cycle would be ~92%
> which is near the maximum for most controller ICs*

It's ~90% duty when operating in continuous conduction mode (CCM) but, if you lower the value of the inductor, you could operate in DCM (discontinuous conduction mode). If your controller permits DCM, it will be at a lower duty cycle. Here's a sample of what I mean from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) with a 33 μH inductor in CCM operating at 100 kHz and 90% duty: -

[image]

If you reduce the inductor to 22 μH you get an 80% duty cycle and DCM operation: -

[image]

The calculator is for ideal components so the percentage duty will be a tad higher. If you wanted to run at closer to 60% duty, you could choose an inductor of about 12 μH.

> *Is there a topology that uses a transformer to achieve such a high
> boost ratio?*

Consider the above modifications first before taking the step to go to a flyback controller (more complex and requires careful selection of the MOSFET and/or leakage flyback snubbing).

If you decide that you need a CCM flyback circuit (1:4 step-up transformer) you can use [this basic "ideal" calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html) (also from my website): -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This probably isnt the answer you're looking for:**

I threw this together because  I had a silly idea after suggesting daisy chained boost converters: what if you were super cheap and didn't want to pay for two controllers? Anyways I napkin'd this and then did the math, which is neat (neglecting diodes, assuming cont curr, etc):

\$V_{stage1}=\frac{V_i}{(1-D)}\$ and \$V_{stage2}=\frac{V_{stage1}}{(1-D)}\$ so if we rearrange for final \$V_o\$ from \$V_i\$ we get:

\$V_{stage2}=\frac{V_i}{(1-D)^2}\$ which means you could get a 10x boost ratio with a 68% duty cycle - cool!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBov5d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One immediate improvement I see is if you managed to use a synchronous boost converter for the first stage you would lose a lot less voltage. You wont be able to pirate the synchronous rectifier signal for the second stage, but it won't mind the diode drop as much as the low voltage stage.

Comment: or perhaps a boost converter chip with multiple outputs?

Comment: @RGBEngineer yeah that’s the smarter, less entertaining way to do it. Looks like a few dual boosts would support this application